# Input and fonts are mutually exclusive on EGLFS QPA

Tags: c++, qt, input, qt5, eglfs

I build *Qt-5.9.2* on *Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS* with *EGLFS* *QPA* enabled.

I switch to terminal on <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd> screen. Then I run my *Qt* application `app` (*Qt Quick* based, if matters):

```
# to debug input
export QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.input=true
# to be able to close by Ctrl+C my application
export QT_QPA_ENABLE_TERMINAL_KEYBOARD=1
~/app -platform eglfs
```

So far so good: it starts normally and all looks fine. But touchscreen and mouse input are not handled by *Qt*. Debug output:

```
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event1' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event1'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event2' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event2'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event0' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event0'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event8' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event8'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event3' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event3'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event4' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event4'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event7' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event7'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event5' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event5'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event6' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event6'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event9' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event9'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event10' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event10'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event11' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event11'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event12' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event12'.
debug: libinput: opening input device '/dev/input/event13' failed (Operation not permitted).
debug: libinput: failed to create input device '/dev/input/event13'.
debug: Using xkbcommon for key mapping
```

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

The next step is to check file permissions for device files:

```
$ ll /dev/input/event*
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 64 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event0
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 65 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event1
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 74 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event10
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 75 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event11
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 76 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event12
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 77 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event13
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 66 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event2
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 67 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event3
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 68 ноя  8 18:38 /dev/input/event4
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 69 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event5
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 70 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event6
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 71 ноя  8 18:38 /dev/input/event7
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 72 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event8
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 73 ноя  8 17:53 /dev/input/event9
```

Okay. I decided to add current user to group `input`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G input $USER
```

Then I relogin on <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd> screen. Now output of `groups` command contains `input` group.

I try again to run my application:

```
~/app -platform eglfs
```

Now it correctly react on mouse and touchscreen input events, but fonts are not rendered - there are even no correctly sized rectangles as placeholders instead of corresponding letters.

I remove the user from group `input`:

```
sudo deluser $USER input
```

Then (after relogin) I try to just change file permissions for input devices:

```
sudo chmod o=g /dev/input/event*
```

Effect is the same. Rollback:

```
sudo chmod o= /dev/input/event*
```

What is the cause of such a behaviour?

Why can't I use both *libinput* and fonts simultaneously?

The workaround is to run the application with root privileges, but it may lead to critical security vulnerability.

Are there specific settings for `libinput` to solve the problem?

Providing ad-hoc fonts also has no effect:

```
wget https://github.com/dejavu-fonts/dejavu-fonts/releases/download/version_2_37/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37.tar.bz2
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Qt-5.9.2/lib/fonts
sudo tar --extract --verbose --strip-components=2 -C /usr/local/Qt-5.9.2/lib/fonts --file dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37.tar.bz2 dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37/ttf/
export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/local/Qt-5.9.2/lib/fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

[Submitted as a bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64377). Solved by adding to `input` group and by removing `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` flag.